# Display alert box for countdown timer

Tags: javascript, html, timer, alert, countdown

I have created a countdown timer which displays the timer within the html.

I have also made it display in an alert box.

My issue is I just want the alert box to display the first time the user accesses the website so it doesn't show on every new page.

I am also having the problem where the alert box pauses the time until you click okay, this makes the times a few seconds behind depending how quick the user clicks okay.

My code is as below.

```
function startTimer(display) {
var date = new Date();
var h17 = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), 17);
if(date.getHours() >= 17) {
    h17.setDate(h17.getDate()+1);
}
h17 = h17.getTime();
var diff,
    hours,
    minutes,
    seconds;

function timer() {
    diff = (((h17 - Date.now()) / 1000) | 0);

    // Setting and displaying hours, minutes, seconds
    hours = (diff / 3600) | 0;
    minutes = ((diff % 3600) / 60) | 0;
    seconds = (diff % 60) | 0;

    hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
};
timer();
setInterval(timer, 1000);
}
window.onload = function () {
    var display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(display);
    alert(display.textContent);
};
```

html below:

```
<div> time left <span id="time"></span> </div>
```

Comment: an alert (as well as a confirmation) box will always halt your code and wait for user interaction. You may want to consider displaying your timer in a div or a new window.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a alert box, you can use a dialog in JavaScript like this [dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

To use it you need to add jQuery and jQuery UI in your document. And then you can initialize the widget with this code :

```
//When the dom is ready
$(function() {
    //This variable contains the countdown interval
    var countdown;

    //Initialization of the widget
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
        open: function( event, ui ) {
            //When the dialog is open we start the countdown
            countdown = startTimer($(this).find('#time')[0])
        },
        close: function( event, ui ) {
            //When the dialog is closed we stop the countdown
            clearInterval(countdown);
        }
    });
});
```

Don't forget to add a `return` on your `setInterval` to get the countdown :

```
return setInterval(timer, 1000);
```

Here is a demo : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nu47ubwq/1/)

References :

- [Dom ready documentation](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)
- [jQueryUI Dialog demo](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)
- [jQueryUI Dialog documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog)
- [`clearInterval` method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp)